# Remove top padding from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView as a cell of another UITableView (nested UITableViews).
There is a top padding that I can't reason for, the top padding only appears when I make the CustomTableCell has a UITableView.

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  private let cellId = "cellId"

  lazy var tableView: UITableView = {

    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.backgroundColor = .green
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false

    tv.separatorColor = .red;
    tv.separatorStyle = .none;

    tv.register(InnerTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellId)
    return tv
  }()

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! InnerTableCell
    return cell
  }

  func setupAutoLayout() {

    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    contentView.addSubview(tableView)
    setupAutoLayout()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Here is the link to entire code: https://ideone.com/QAxkPR

Here is how it looks in reveal
[image]

Comment: Does height of parent table static / dynamic ?

Comment: It is static, based on the height of the inner table view. Here is the link to entire code: https://ideone.com/QAxkPR

Comment: can you change .grouped to .plain

Comment: thank you, changing it to .plain fixed the issue but do you know why it happens?

Comment: group changes always has a header that you did not implemented so it's space is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change style to `.plain` instead of `.grouped`

```
let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
```

Answer (score -1):

This padding gets added automatically if you use the `.plain` table style.

**More on TableView styles here:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style

You can fix it by switching to `.grouped` if that works for your use case - however this will prevent the section headers from anchoring to the top and staying in view.

An alternative fix if you want to keep using `.plain` style tables is to set
`tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0`